# Dates check in loop?

Tags: java, loops, validation, date

I have an assignment to create a Date class with given methods requests.
One of those methods give back the day of the week in integer, where **1=Sunday.....6=Friday, and 0=Saturday**.
this is the method:

```
public int dayInWeek () {
    int day, month;
    int year;    //2 last numbers of the year
    int century; //2 first numbers of the year
    if(_month==1 || _month==2) {
        day= _day;
        month= _month + 12;
        year= (_year-1) % 100;
        century= (_year-1) / 100;
    }
    else {
        day= _day;
        month= _month;
        year= _year % 100;
        century= _year / 100;
    }

    return (day + (26*(month+1))/10 + year + year/4 + century/4 - 2*century)%7;
}
```

Now, after receiving the day of the week, the assignment hints that there may be a date(s) where the result may be a negative. 
I tried to make a `main()` that will loop through all days months and years from the given range years 1800-2100, but only got more and more confused and lost.
Ii'd appreciate it if someone could hint me how to make it happen, without all those existing calender/date/etc classes because it just gets messy for me like this.
Thanks.

edit: more info:

```
//constructors
/**
 * creates a new Date object if the date is valid, otherwise creates the date 1/1/2000
 * @param _day the day of the month (1-31)
 * @param _month the month in the year (1-12)
 * @param _year the year (1800-2100)
 */
public Date (int day, int month, int year) {
    if (isValidDate (day, month, year)) {
        _day=day;
        _month=month;
        _year=year;           
    }
    else {
        setToDefault();
    }
}

/**
 * copy constructor 
 * @param other the date to be copied
 */
public Date (Date other) {
    _day= other._day;
    _month= other._month;
    _year= other._year;
}
//methods
private boolean isValidDate(int day, int month, int year) {
    if (year<MIN_YEAR || year>MAX_YEAR) {
        return false;
    }
    if (month<MIN_MONTH || month>MAX_MONTH) {
        return false;
    }
    if (day<MIN_DAY) {
        return false;
    }
    switch (month) {
        case 1:
        case 3:
        case 5:
        case 7:
        case 8:
        case 10:
        case 12: return day<=31;
        case 4:
        case 6:
        case 9:
        case 11: return day<=30;

        default: return leap(year) ? day<=29 : day<=28; //month==2;
    }        
}

/**
 * check if leap year
 * @param y year to check
 * @return true if given year is leap year
 */
private static boolean leap (int y) {
    return (y % 4 == 0 && y % 100 != 0) || (y % 400 == 0);
}
```

*i* hope that's enough.

Comment: Can you please add the missing bits& pieces, i.e. information on `_month`, ' _year'. How are these values defined?

Comment: @StefanFreitag hey, just added constructor and the methods it uses.
_day/_month/_year are instance variables of the Date class

Comment: From your general description it’s very hard to understand why you get confused. Could you add some examples of dates with expected result and how observed result differs? I’m sure it’ll help.

Comment: @OleV.V. that is the problem. the hint clearly says the dayInWeek may return a negative, where all my manual checks produced the correct result. that's why i tried to make the program run through all dates and if the dayInWeek results in a negative, print that date so i can see what's causing the problem.
but that's also where it got real messy for me and i lost direction and got confused on how to make that run-through check correctly.

for example, d1.dayInWeek(), where d1 is a Date object with the date 24.3.18 in it, will produce the integer 6(=friday).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a negative result when the year is 2100. Test with today's date (month = 3, date = 24, year = 2100) and you can see it gives a negative number.

If you take a look at [Code implementation for Zeller's congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence#Implementation_in_software), you can avoid the problem by changing your formula to:

```
return dayOfWeek= (day + (26*(month+1))/10 + year + year/4 + century/4+ 5*century)%7;
```

Comment: care to explain why the change of -2 to +5 affects the day calculation, and how you got to that formula?

Comment: Sure, updated the answer so there's a source, please check it out. Hope it helps!